# Convert String from CoreData into CLLocationDegrees/ CLLocationCoordinate2D

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, coordinates, cllocation

I had been struggling to store CLLocationCoordinate2D data from markers on a google maps to CoreData. This cannot be done directly but I found a work around where I take the coordinates, split into CLLocationDegrees, convert it into a string text and store it. I do this by the following:

```
    let marker = GMSMarker()
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(place.coordinate.latitude, place.coordinate.longitude)

    let newPlaceLatitude = place.coordinate.latitude
    print(newPlaceLatitude)
    var latitudeText:String = "\(newPlaceLatitude)"
   self.latitudeText = "\(newPlaceLatitude)"
    let newPlaceLongitude = place.coordinate.longitude
    print(newPlaceLongitude)
    var longitudeText:String = "\(newPlaceLongitude)"
self.longitudeText = "\(newPlaceLongitude)"
```

Storing into CoreData:

```
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let newPlace = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: 
     "StoredPlace", into: context)
     newPlace.setValue(latitudeText, forKeyPath: "latitude")
    newPlace.setValue(longitudeText, forKeyPath: "longitude")
```

However now I am struggling to reconstruct the strings back into CLLocationCoordinates. How would I turn a string to a CLLocationDegree/CLLocationCoordinate2D ? This is supposedly pretty simple but I have found that the following method doesn't work:

```
    let latitude:  CLLocationDegrees = Double(latitudeText)!
                let longitude: CLLocationDegrees = Double(longitudeText)!
                    let markers = GMSMarker()
                print(latitude)
                print(longitude)
                    markers.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
```

any other suggestions about how to change string to coordinate?

Comment: Probably not related but why do you store a `Double` as `String` to convert it back to `Double`? Core Data supports `Double` as well.

Comment: What became of this?

Comment: The reason why I wasn't storing it as double straight away is because I kept getting errors and couldn't get round it so thought this method of double to string- string to double would work just as well.. Adrian I didn't fully understand your answer so ended up using the method of converting the string back to double in the viewDidLoad when fetching the data from coredata by using:  if let lat = result.value(forKey: "latitude") as? NSString { let latitude = (lat as NSString).doubleValue } and using that to reconstruct markers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `typecast` your lat and long in decimal values, more preferable is double instead of float because of precision value which can drop pins at perfect locations.

Type casting in `double` using as keyword:

```
(yourCordinateString as NSString).doubleValue
```

casting in `float` values:

```
(yourCordinateString as NSString).floatValue
```

Comment: This works without error but something strange is happening when I do this method. The retrieved values come out as 0.0 even though when i store it and print the string it is the correct value. However when i do print after the above method it goes to 0.0, any idea why that is?

Comment: Sure, I have put the code onto the end of my question above. Please have a look. I am implementing this code in the viewDidLoad of the viewcontroller which I have my map container. the print(latitudeText) etc works fine but print(latitude) come out as 0.0 in the terminal. Any thoughts about what going on?

Comment: eh I figured out why its 0.0, because latitudeText is the wrong thing I am calling! i need result.value(forKey: "latitude")...

Comment: that's what i saw in your updated ques, lat long text is not correct from source .

Answer (score 1):

`CLLocation`'s `latitude` and `longitude` are doubles, so with that in mind, you might consider having `latitude` and `longitude` properties that are doubles on your `StoredPlace` object. I called the properties `coordinateX` and `coordinateY` so it's easier to remember that they're custom coordinates, not "factory" properties.

You could create an extension in a file called **StoredPlace+Extension.swift** that looks like this:

```
import CoreData
import CoreLocation

extension StoredPlace {
    func location() -> CLLocation {
        let location = CLLocation(latitude: self.coordinateX, longitude: self.coordinateY)
        return location
    }
}
```

With this extension, you can then get the coordinates out of your results as follows:

```
for result in results {
    print("coordinate = \(result.location().coordinate)")
    print("latitude = \(result.location().coordinate.latitude)")
    print("longitude = \(result.location().coordinate.longitude)")
}
```